# Qt5 ui(new Ui::WidgetManage) incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, qt5

When I complie it, there are some errors that shows "ui(new Ui::WidgetManage) incomplete type is not allowed" , I just want to add a child widget to the mainwindow,which can respond for the button in the mainwindow,I have tried many times but still don't know where should I correct.
**Here is widget_manage.h**

````
#ifndef WIDGET_MANAGE_H
#define WIDGET_MANAGE_H

#include<QWidget>

namespace Ui {
  class WidgetManage;
}

class WidgetManage :public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  WidgetManage(QWidget* parent);
  ~WidgetManage();
protected slots:
  void click_load();
private:
  Ui::WidgetManage* ui;
};
#endif // !WIDGET_MANAGE_H```



#include "ui_widget_manage.h"
#include "widget_manage.h"

WidgetManage::WidgetManage(QWidget* parent):QWidget(parent),ui(new Ui::WidgetManage)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}
````

Comment: Do you know what it means for something to be an incomplete type?

Comment: I think it may be can't find where to define this type，or the type doesn't have its size

Comment: @maoPoker That's close enough. So ask yourself: why does the compiler know where `WidgetManage` is defined (you are defining one of its methods, so the definition has to be known), but the compiler does not know where `Ui::WidgetManage` is defined? What's different?

Comment: In my opinion, I think WidgetManage is a class under the Ui namespace, when I use WidgetManage, I should include its dot h file, "widget_manage.h" and "ui_widget_manage.h", but it  doesn't work. I use the same way to create a MainWindow, however, it works. So I'm a bit confused

Comment: Show your `pro` file.

Comment: @maoPoker You've jumped some steps without realizing it. Think more literally. What is the difference between the names "`WidgetManage`" and "`Ui::WidgetManage`"? (Look at the letters -- which are different?)

Comment: Hmm... we might have lost the OP. Well, the answer to my question is that one name starts with `Ui::` while the other does not. Apparently, there is some significance to that. As you mull over what that significance might be, you'll prime your brain to understand the answer to the original question, or perhaps come up with the answer yourself. (If there is still interest in such an answer, ping me in these comments. If I'm still around, I'll post one.)

Comment: @ JaMiT Thanks for your patience, I think one name with UI means  that something is under it's definations, to let the complier know where is defined. But I just stuck in this question why I use correct namespace and its class, it still show errors.